# use c++ lib in flash builder as3 project

Tags: c++, actionscript-3

Is it possible to use c++ lib inside as3 project? (flash builder 4.7)

I have a project writen in c++ and I want to build the gui with flash.
I'm seracing for a way to use flash and work with my c++ lib

Comment: Yep... Air application for android

Comment: You might be out of luck. You could access Java code in Android, but I do not think you can do C++, at least not through AIR. You might be able to compile to ABC (ActionScript Byte Code), but I have no experience with that and I have no idea how to do it or if it would even work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that a [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) GUI is actually some Web interface. Then, you need some HTTP server library in C++, like the [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion) library, the network part of [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) libraries, or the [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) library.

<sup>BTW, perhaps making a pure HTML5 + Javascript interface is easier and more portable, with the real work done in C++.</sup>

Comment: It is not for web use but for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for, but you could use FlasCC http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/docs/Reference.html That imposes some requirements on your lib, but I think nothing that #define-s cannot handle )