# HTTP request by sockets in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I have one problem with HTTP request created by C++ sockets (Linux). I need to get some information's from API.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int sock;
struct sockaddr_in client;
int PORT = 80;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct hostent * host = gethostbyname("api.themoviedb.org");

    if ( (host == NULL) || (host->h_addr == NULL) ) {
        cout << "Error retrieving DNS information." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&client, sizeof(client));
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    memcpy(&client.sin_addr, host->h_addr, host->h_length);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock < 0) {
        cout << "Error creating socket." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client)) < 0 ) {
        close(sock);
        cout << "Could not connect" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    stringstream ss;
    ss << "GET /3/movie/" << 550 << "?api_key=xxx HTTP/1.1\r\n"
       << "Host: api.themoviedb.org\r\n"
       << "Accept: application/json\r\n"
       << "\r\n\r\n";
    string request = ss.str();

    if (send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0) != (int)request.length()) {
        cout << "Error sending request." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    char cur;
    while ( read(sock, &cur, 1) > 0 ) {
        cout << cur;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that it takes too long. It start writing response to console but it ends in 9/10 and after it takes about 30 seconds to end. When i tried to change in loop from:

```
cout << cur;
```

To:

```
cout << cur << endl;
```

Then it write a complete result but after it the program lags for a while. What is wrong with this code? When i tried get response by classic curl from terminal everything was OK. Thanks for your help

Comment: Use a library (probably `libcurl` for HTTP client). see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17681598/841108) for HTTP library server side.

Comment: Also - you are sending one too many "\r\n" - wont affect you if you wont re-use the connection - but worth nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web server is probably holding the connection open awaiting your next HTTP request, which will never come.  The server eventually times out and closes the connection.  You can change this behavior by either:

1. requesting the server close the connection with a `Connection: close` header line in the request
2. parsing the response header to know when to stop reading once you have gotten the end of the response. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) for the rules of how to detect the end of the response.

Comment: `Connection: close` does the trick here - but as[rfc2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) does mandate that the tcp connection be closed if client sends `Connection: close` this is just a nasty hack. The content length approach is best - but really libcurl will be superior in all respects.

Comment: Ok thanks the 1) helped me... It's working but i will try the second too. I'm doing this for study purposes and I want to try it by sockets. But really thanks for the `libcurl` too.

Comment: `Content-Length` is not the only thing you have to look for in a response. If the response is chunked, there will not be any `Content-Length` header (and if there is, it must be ignored). The HTTP 1.1 spec mandates that both client and server implementations must recognize and support chunking.

Answer (score 2):

You could have used HTTP/1.0 as the version on the request, since 1.0 version determines that the server should close the connection after each request.